# What is the different between or and ori in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, mips, spim

I'm doing a homework assignment and I am puzzled with which one I should use. What does the i add to the command.

Answer (score 8):

- `OR` performs the bitwise OR operation between *two registers*.
- `ORI` performs the bitwise OR operation between *one register, and an immediate value*

If you have two registers you want to OR together, then use `OR`. If you want to `OR` a register with some constant value, use `ORI`.

Questions like this should always be addressed by first consulting an [instruction set reference](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html).